# Part of the row to columns

Tags: sql-server

I would like to select from a table with prices and move some of the data in the rows to columns.

Currently I have a table like this:

| Date | Time | PriceName | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-11-01 | 1 | Price1 | 20 |
| 2015-11-01 | 1 | Price2 | 33 |
| 2015-11-01 | 1 | Price3 | 50 |

And would like to select a table like this:

| Date | Time | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-11-01 | 1 | 20 | 33 | 50 |

I know I can select a table like this with joins, is it still a good idea to do it with joins if I have 15+ PriceNames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will help you

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(Dates DATE,Times INT, PriceName NVARCHAR(44),Price INT)

INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES
('2015-11-01',1,'Price1',20),
('2015-11-01',1,'Price2',33),
('2015-11-01',1,'Price3',50)

SELECT *
FROM @T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Price)
    FOR PriceName IN ([Price1], [Price2], [Price3])
)AS pivots
```

you can create dynamic query also

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + PriceName
            FROM @T c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT *
FROM @T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Price)
    FOR PriceName IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pivots'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, tried pivot before but couldnt get it to work properly.